# Plot factor by frequency

Tags: r, plot

I have a factor `a`:

```
> a
[1]  foo                                                    
[2]  bar                      
[3]  foo                                
[4]  baz                                                     
[5]  bar
[6]  foo
```

I want to `plot()` this factor but only including levels with a minimum frequency of two. So that only foo and bar are plotted, not baz.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just use standard subsetting. First, create some table:

```
d = factor(sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE))
```

next, create a table of frequencies:

```
freq_tab = table(d)
```

Finally, subset and plot:

```
barplot(freq_tab[freq_tab>=2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution was to use function `summary` in combination with `as.factor`:

```
summary(as.factor(a)) -> b
barplot(b[b>=2])
```